# Asp.net MVC update a web page without reloading the page after 15 seconds using ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc-5

Referring to my question i want to update a page i.e. refresh the page only after every `15` seconds without reloading it.For now i am using `<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="15">` it updates the page while reloading it and it's not a good approach as it reloads the page which doesn't look good. So for that i want to use `ajax` which will update/refresh my page without reloading after every 15 seconds.

My target `url` is `http://localhost:17104/Home/MultiGraph`

I have searched many articles on it and found that the ajax is using he data to update the page. I just want to update/refresh the page without reloading

**Updated Code:**

I have used `setInterval` and in it i have placed my ajax call like bellow

```
setInterval(function () {
    $.ajax({
        url: '/Home/MultiGraph',
        type: "POST",
        success: function (result) {
            $("#charts").html(result);
            alert(result);
        }
    });
    //chart1.redraw();
    //alert("hello");
}, 8000);
```

While in my alert it's showing me some hideous data

[image]

After i press `ok` i get the bellow result

[image]

Also in ajax call `charts` is my `div` in which my charts are placed

```
 <div id="charts">
    <div id="container1" style="height: 400px; width:auto"></div>


    <div id="container2" style="height: 400px; width:auto"></div>


    <div id="container3" style="height: 400px; width:auto"></div>


    <div id="container4" style="height: 400px; width:auto"></div>
</div>
```

Any help would be highly appreciated

Comment: What part of the page do you want to refresh?

Comment: @StephenMuecke the target url, i have charts in it so data is coming from a meter after every 15-20 seconds

Comment: You mean the whole page? - that is just the same as 'reloading'

Comment: you are in the right path, ajax exposes success function and inside that function you can do DOM manipulation there, no reload required unless you force it

Comment: @Div it's just using javascript i want to use ajax as well

Comment: @MidTwo you means to say that i should use `setInterval` or `setTimeout` and then place my ajax in it ?

Comment: @faisal1208, If you just going to be calling the same method that generated the view in the first place, then there is no point - its going to download the whole view again. Use ajax if you only want to update part of the page.

Comment: @faisal1208 definitely yes, fire your ajax request after a certain period of time. But I'm wondering why I need to wait for that long to fetch data. But you can use settimeout

Comment: @StephenMuecke kindly see the updated code

Comment: @MidTwo Kindly see the updated code

Comment: @faisal1208 specify the data type property of your ajax, what response format you are expecting

Comment: You need to return `PartialView()` when you do a ajax call.. else it will return the entire page with layout too..

Comment: Because you returning the whole view and adding it inside the `<div id="charts">` - you need to return just a partial view of only what you want to update in the DOM (there is no point returning the whole page again). Which bit of your view is changing?

Comment: yes @StephenMuecke and Reddy is correct

Comment: @StephenMuecke the charts and the table shown in right bottom

Comment: Then you ajax call should make a call to a server method that returns a partial view of only that html

Comment: @StephenMuecke is there any sample on it ? i am new to this stuff

Comment: [mvc update partial view with ajax](https://www.google.com.au/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=mvc%20update%20partial%20view%20with%20ajax)

Comment: @StephenMuecke Thank you i'll give it a try

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Problem:** you are pulling the layout along with your view.

**Solution:** You need to **return a partial view when ever you request from a Ajax call**, Else the enitre HTML along with your Layout page will be passed by the server.

To check if the request was made from Ajax or not you can do as below. This is just a pseudo code.

```
if (Request.IsAjaxRequest())
{
   return PartialView(); //you can pass in some data into view as PartialView(myModel)
}
 return View();
```

So you can have the same ActionResult and all other logics in it and just add this `if` check at the end to toggle between a full view and a partial view.

Also point to note: **Make sure your view does not have the Layout setting code**.

ie: Something like below.

```
@{
   Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}
```

If you have this and try to do a `return PartialView();` it will not work, It will still return you the Layout. So make sure you remove the layout settings line of code.

After that has been taken care of the default layout will be used when you actually do a `return View();` And a view with the layout will be returned when you use `return PartialView();`.

**Which is your default view?** You can get that information if you look at the file `_ViewStart.cshtml` in your Views folder.

Comment: In my code the default view for `MultiGraph` is `_MLayout`

Comment: @faisal1208 ok so what is the default layout inside the `_ViewStart.cshtml` file?

Comment: it's `@{
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}`

Comment: @faisal1208 you can add the same `if` check in the view page too.. that means instead of the logic in the controller add the same check and toggle the use of layout. you can have your controller to just return view..

Answer (score 0):

```
success: function (result) {
            $("#charts").html(result);
            alert(result);
        }
```

where "result" above is a string which represents the entire page... so it would be the same as redirecting to the same url for a refresh of the page.

problem there is no target element which you could target to do this... ie

```
$('html').replaceWith(result);
```

is close but its not the entire page.

anyway your main problem is steamed from targeting the wrong target for the whole page $("#charts"), but the problem is that with the data in result you would not be able to achieve the effect you wanted anyway with changing this to $('html')

so i would suggest that you change the data which is returned from '/Home/MultiGraph' and create a new controller action which only renders the portion you want.

This can be archived with MVC Partialview("ViewName", viewModel)

Hope this helps